# Suggestion of books of Topology and Graph Theory

Tags: general-topology, graph-theory, book-recommendation

I would like to know if you can give some advices of books with relation of Graph Theory and Topology. When I search in Google, I only find some articles with very hard theory, and i am looking for an introduction. Thanks.

Comment: Topology without tears has been a good read for me so far, and has been made availible online.

Comment: @Kaynex but does that book cover those topics? Becouse I am learning  graph theory with Douglas West and Topology with Munkres, but non of them mix their topics.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such book that I know of, and I can the subject matter would not be very broad:
We can see a (finite) graph as a simplicial space, a glueing together of copies of $[0,1]$ at a skeleton of isolated points. The only topological questions I know of here, is embedding it into $\mathbb{R}^2$ or $\mathbb{R}^3$: they all can be embedded in the latter, the planar ones in the former, and we have Kuratowski's criterion for that, and [many others](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_graph).

Also some algebraic topology books compute homology groups of such "graph spaces", as a nice application of general theorems.

I cannot really think of other areas of overlap, off hand. Maybe others can add some ideas as well.